# Native software on dedicated machine vs virtualizing services on dedicated machine

Tags: virtualization, openvz, proxmox

I used to have a VPS, and the benefits of a VPS are pretty obvious: instant snapshots, instant booting, instant and one click changes rollback (so if I mess up really bad, even losing network connection, I only need to login to my VPS panel, and restore the state of my server in a single click).

But now I need more power, and 8 cores, 8 GB of RAM for about 15 euros seems pretty decent, considering now I have full kernel access and I have full 100% control over my server. Thiscomes with a few drawbacks: Obviously, frictionless backups are gone, and even if I set up a backup system myself, I'd still have to login via SSH to issue a few commands and restore my data. Obviously this is going to take longer than the one click restore from my VPS panel.

So I thought about installing proxmox and deploying my services as VMs, with the advantage of the control a dedicated server gives me, and extreme graularity. So if my web server is compromised, my other virtual instances, such as my mail server, or my database server, won't be, and with a single click I can roll back changes.

The question is: Is it really worth it to virtualize (using OpenVZ or LXC, maybe, for little to no performance hit) my servers individually for more control over my infrastructure and easier backups or are there actual solutions in place for easily backing up a dedicated server and restoring it to a previous point in time? Or, on the other hand, the hassle of setting up every virtual instance and managing a few virtual servers (rather than a "big" dedicated one) outweighs the easy backup configuration of said setup?

I'm aware this might come more to personal preference, but the matter of fact, is that I don't have enough arguments for or against each option to make an informed decision, plus I'm rather a beginner in system administration, and would like to know if companies actually deploy these kind of setups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenVZ is a mature project and have only little overhead in performance.
Managment it's a lot easier with vps backups but with bigger containers like 50GB there may be need of tweaking vzdump and/or LVM allocation.

Depending on what you will be using in containers, OpenVZ is not reliable as for example KVM. 
Live migration without shared storage is a great feature but sometimes it breaks without apparent reason.
Bandwidth limiting also needs tweaking in OpenVZ. KVM in proxmox have way more out of the box features but overhead is much bigger.